# Создание экземпляра интерфейса

Tags: java, ооп, классы, объекты, интерфейс

Недавно наткнулся на странный вид создания экземпляра интерфейса. Я знаю, что создавать экземпляры абстрактных классов и интерфейсов нельзя, но данная запись выглядит как-то странно.

Вопрос заключается в следующем: как можно охарактеризовать данную запись?

```java
public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Animal() {
            //?
            @Override
            public void say() {
                System.out.println("i am animal");
            }
        };
    }

    public interface Animal {
        void say();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Это - конструкция создания экземпляра анонимного класса. Она создаёт класс, унаследованный от класса/интерфейса `Animal`. Экземпляры абстрактных классов и интерфейсов создавать, действительно, нельзя, но в данном случае анонимный класс (пере)определяет метод `say` и класс перестаёт быть абстрактным.

Фактически, данный код

```
Animal animal = new Animal() {
    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("i am animal");
    }
};
```

эквивалентен следующему:

```
class AnonAnimal implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("i am animal");
    }
};
Animal animal = new AnonAnimal();
```